# Vectorized dot product

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, dot-product

I have a pandas dataframe, and one of the columns has a list in each row. I have a separate numpy array, `query_ebd`, which I want to dot with every row in that column. The output I want is one number per row, representing the dot product of the list in that row with `query_ebd`. Currently, I am doing:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    chat_result = query_ebd.dot(row[2])
```

This works, but it's slow. I am trying to vectorize this function but I can't get it to work. I tried:

```
chat_result = df['Embedding'].dot(query_ebd)
```

but I get a dot-product shape mismatch because it is trying to dot the column with `query_ebd` rather than dot each row with it. How can I make it dot each row? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the expected output and a minimal input?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to multiply a column containing lists by a numpy array of column's length.

Consider below example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col':[[1,2,3], [1,2]]
})
query_ebd = np.array([2,4])
```

Let's create a seprate column for `query_ebd` and perform row-wise list multiplication.

```
df['mul'] = query_ebd
chat_result = df.apply(lambda x: [y * int(x['mul']) for y in x['col']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    [2, 4, 6]
1       [4, 8]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what I am trying to  do. Each row of the column contains a list `L_i`, and I want to dot each list with `query_ebd`, thus the output I want is a dot product for each row, and I want to vectorize this. `query_ebd` has the same length (256) as each list `L_i`.

Comment: @Luciano if your data-frame of `dtype=object` vectorization will be of no avail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.col.transform(lambda k: query_ebd.dot(k))
```

---

Just re-read your quesiton and now I understand what you want.

I believe this is a good solution, but I'm open to critics.

You can define your own type and overwrite `__mul__`, and let built-in implementation of numpy to do the vectorization for you

```
class O(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def __mul__(self, o):
        return np.dot(self.d, o.d)

 df.col.transform(O) * O(query_ebd)
```

---

Using this sample data,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col':[ ([1,2,3]), ([1,2,0])]
})

query_ebd = np.array([2,4,3])

df.col.transform(O) * O(query_ebd)

0    19
1    10
```

---

Peformance:

For a 2 million rows data frame,

```
%timeit v * O(query_ebd)
4.5 s ± 230 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit s.transform(lambda k: query_ebd.dot(k))
12.4 s ± 264 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This isn't vectorized.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Understand the question now.. maybe have a solution

Comment: Tbh have no idea whether vectorization is going on underneath for this case. IMO it would make sense to be, but maybe having `O` objects adds too much overhead?

Comment: Well, `dtype=object` will blunt the advantages of vectorization significantly. It removes the locality of reference which is probably the major source of speed improvements. However, the looping is pushed down into the C-level, so it should be faster, but not the 50x or 100x (or more) speed ups you'd expect with primitive numerical types.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Seems that there is no solution then because OP has a collection of iterables by definition, so `dtype` is object no matter the method

Comment: @RafaelC I have control over the data type of the vectors. I'm currently parsing them into a list from a string of text using `df['Embedding'] = df['Embedding'].str.split(',').apply(lambda s: list(map(float, s)))`. Is there a different structure that would be better?